# matplotlib NaN's vs pylab NaN's

Tags: python, matplotlib, interpolation, nan

I have two similar pieces of matplotlib codes that produce different results.

1:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,10,100)
y = np.linspace(0,10,100)
y[10:40] = np.nan
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.savefig('fig')
```

2:

```
from pylab import *

x = linspace(0,10,100)
y = linspace(0,10,100)
y[10:40] = np.nan
plot(x,y)
savefig('fig')
```

Code #1 produces a straight line with the NaN region filled in with a solid line of a different color

Code #2 produces a figure with a straight line but does not fill in the NaN region with a line. Instead there is a gap there.

How can I make code # 1 produce a gap in place of NaN's like code #2. I have been googling for a couple of days and have come up with nothing. Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Those two are identical. The only way you'd get "a straight line with the NaN region filled in with a solid line of a different color"  is if you plotted the same line twice, and the first didn't have the `NaN`s.  Are you running those two pieces of code together? If so, they'll plot on the same figure.

Comment: I get identical figures using the inline backend. Which backend are you using?

Comment: You're almost definitely seeing the effects of plotting you did in the same `ipython` (or similar) session.  It's a good idea to always explicitly create a new figure if you're working in long-running interactive sessions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to explain what's probably happening:

The two pieces of code you showed are identical. They will always produce the same output if called by themselves. `pylab` is basically a just a few lines of code that does: (There's a bit more to it than this, but it's the basic idea.)

```
from numpy import *
from matplotlib.mlab import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
```

There's absolutely no way for `pylab.plot` to reference a different function than `plt.plot`

---

However, if you just call `plt.plot` (or `pylab.plot`, they're the same function), it plots on the *current* figure.

If you plotted something on that figure before, it will still be there. (If you're familiar with matlab, matplotlib defaults to `hold('on')`. You can change this with `plt.hold`, but it's best to be more explicit in python and just create a new figure.)

Basically, you probably did this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,10,100)
y = np.linspace(0,10,100)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.savefig('fig')
```

And then, in the same interactive `ipython` session, you did this:

```
y[10:40] = np.nan
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.savefig('fig')
```

Because you didn't call `show`, the current figure is still the same one as it was before. The "full" line is still present beneath the second one, and the second line with the NaN's is a different color because you've plotted on the same axes.

This is one of the many reasons why it's a good idea to use the object-oriented interface. That way you're aware of *exactly* which axes and figure you're plotting on.

For example:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
fig.savefig('test.png')
```

If you're not going to do that, at very least always explicitly create a new figure and/or axes when you want a new figure. (e.g. start by calling `plt.figure()`)

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I am running the pieces of code in different python shells and I am using the object-oriented interface in my program.

Comment: Yes you are right. I was redrawing over the previous one. However in my program, I am making a new figure every time and then plotting. I know this because when I change my data set the previous line goes away and is replaced by another line but with the NaN region  still filled in with a line

Comment: @user3365990 - What datatype are your arrays? `NaN` is a floating-point-only value.  If you assign NaNs to an integer array, they'll be a large negative number instead of a NaN.

Comment: I have a list of longs with np.nan that I convert to np arrays like this: y_array = np.array(y). y is a list.

Comment: @user3365990 - Without a bit more information, I'm just guessing, but try explicitly specifying the dtype for the array. E.g. `np.array(y, dtype=float)`

Comment: Basically what I am doing is this: fig = Figure(figsize=(8.5,2.5)); canvas = FigureCanvas(fig); ax = fig.add_subplot(111); y_array = np.array(y, dtype = float); x_array = np.array(x, dtype=float); ax.plot(x_array, y_array, ); buffer = StringIO.StringIO(); canvas = FigureCanvas(fig); canvas.draw(); pilImage = PIL.Image.fromstring("RGB", canvas.get_width_height(), canvas.tostring_rgb()); pilImage.save(buffer, "PNG")

Comment: Just for the record, there's no need to jump through all of those hoops with PIL.  Just to `fig.canvas.print_png(buffer)`.  Also you don't need to explicitly initialize a `Figure` and `FigureCanvas` object, unless you want to take a more complex route. You can just use `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`. If you want to use a specific backend (e.g. `Agg` for a webserver), just call `matplotlib.use(backend)` before importing pyplot.

Comment: However, I can't see anything wrong with what you posted. Can you provide a stand-alone example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Found the error. My data was not sorted. Thanks for your help.